# Сумма соседних элементов в матрице

Tags: python

не могу понять как двигаться дальше, вроде бы строку и столбцы нашёл, но не знаю правильно ли,  как мне найти сумму соседних элементов, направьте в правильное русло мышления

```py
b = input()
a = []
while b != 'end':
    a.append([int(i) for i in b.split()])
    b = input()
for row in range(len(a)):
    for col in range(len(a[row])):
```

Comment: Правильное русло мышления (я бы как действовал): начать с того, чтобы понять самому, правильно ли найдены строка и столбцы (должен быть тестовый пример), далее - ясно сформулировать, в чем именно проблема с поиском суммы соседних элементов и либо самому ответ станет ясен, либо спросить тут конкретно уже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на просторах интернета нашел один лайфхак, когда мы итерируем и боимся выйти за пределы индекса, нужно вычесть из координаты длину объекта, так перейдем в обратное индексирование для вашего случая сумма соседних по строке(для первого: второй и последний) выглядит так :

```
s = a[col][row-1] + a[col][row-len(row)+1]
```